# Breathing practice for harmonica

Tags: practice, harmonica, breathing

What are some good breathing practices for playing the harmonica? I have been learning the harmonica for a while now, I can play small time rhymes and some songs.

But when I try to get into high intensity mode or try to play continuous blows or draws. Or even when I try to play continuously for a long time, I run out of gas. Also during that time my notes get all messed up, I start drawing and blowing randomly(probably gasping for breath) and loose all my concentration and have to try again.

Due to this I never end up completing a song completely. Are there any good breathing practices to overcome this?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to practice the breathing as it is done with some of the woodwinds and brass. Here are some basic guidelines:

1. Don't try to play a song as the first thing when you get your hands on the harmonica.
2. Learn how to **breathe with the [diaphragm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoracic_diaphragm)**. Many of us don't really know that this is the best way to breathe, regardless of the goal.
3. **Play** lots and lots of **long notes**. Before starting to play any song, play long notes. This will strengthen your body's "air column".
4. In the songs you are playing and/or trying to learn, make sure to **mark some "checkpoints" to breathe** and change them according to your current endurance. Then, try to do it again but with a little more time between the breathing spots. This way, you can improve your endurance while playing, since you would try to follow this breathing check points.
5. Try to do **distinguish between phrases** as you do when sing.

Answer (score 1):

There are no secrets. Try playing the same song many times looking where you can breathe. After long pratice, you will automatically find where you can breathe.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of trivia from me:

Besides what has been already mentioned, there's this technique called [circular breathing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_breathing). Once learned, it basically allows you to blow constantly for a long period of time.

It's by no means essential for harmonica players, but I believe that it might be useful sometimes, and in fact practicing it (even when not playing) is a nice breathing exercise by itself!

Answer (score 0):

There's more to using the diaphragm than just pushing with your abdomenal muscles and ignoring your chest and shoulders. Often this is over-stressed when introducing breathing awareness to new students.

One useful thing to do once or twice at the start of practice is a Full-Yogi breath.

- Start breathing-in normally, pushing the abdomen out.
- Then firm-up the diaphragm and pull the abdomen *in* to stretch the chest, shoulders and back, inflating the upper parts of the lungs.
- Then firm-up the ribs and shoulders and push the abdomen out *again*.
- Then release, breathe-out. And breathe normally.

This gives you the deepest possible breath, like a stretch. But don't over-do it; it can lead to hyper-oxygenation and make you loopy. Doing it just once or twice will help open-up the lungs and make your normal breathing more productive for a time.